# bash script to batch truncate filenames in one dir

Tags: bash

this question is somewhat unique among others asked.
i have a dir with a bunch of folders and they are named using periods to separate every word.
such as: foo.bar.2011.useless.words
the last two words are always the useless ones, so i would like to truncate starting with the second to last period.
not sure of the wording...
many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for file in *.*.*
do
  mv "$file" "${file%.*.*}"
done
```

Comment: One minor criticism: You'll want to use `for file in *.*.*/` to limit the pattern matching only to directories. As you have it now you'll match `this.is.a.file`

Comment: thanks, one thing that confuses me: "for file in '*.*.*'  does it matter how many "." are actually in the folder name? for example, if the folder name has 6 or so "." in it?

Comment: @bboyreason `*.*.*` matches any file or folder that has *at least* two dots in its name.  For the reason I mentioned in my comment to Ignacio, I would use `*.*.*/` so it *only* matches folders with at least two dots in its name, and not files.

Comment: perfect, i understand that naming convention now. thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

If your folders with dots are only one level deep, go with Ignacio's answer.  However, if you have folders that you want to rename that exist in subdirs such as `/toplevel/subdir1/foo.bar.baz.blah/` then you'll need to use my `find` command below.  Unless you have `Bash 4.x` in which case you can use the `shopt -s globstar` option.

```
find /top/level/dir -type d -name '*.*.*' -exec sh -c 'for arg; do echo mv "$arg" "${arg%.*.*}"; done' _ {} +
```

I added an `echo` in there so you can do a dry-run without making any changes. Remove the `echo` if you are satisfied with the output and run it again to make the changes permanent.

**Edit**
Removed my `$tmp` var by shamelessly stealing Ignacio's PE

Comment: thanks for the help, valuable tools no doubt, possibly answer question in above comment if you feel like it...